# Limit as $x \to 1$ of $\frac{x^3}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 1} \left( \frac{x^3}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-1} \right) = 3$$

I am having trouble figuring out how to factor out $x-1$ so to execute the proof.

Comment: *Hint:* $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following up on comments (including a follow up comment which has been deleted):

$$ \frac{x^3}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{x^3 - 1}{x - 1} = \frac{(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1)}{x-1} = x^2 + x + 1$$

Hence

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left( \frac{x^3}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-1} \right) = \lim_{x \to 1}  \ (x^2 + x + 1) = \cdots $$

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^3-1}{x-1}.$$

By definition of the derivative, the limit of this is $f'(1),$ where $f(x) = x^3.$ Thus the answer is $3\cdot 1^2 = 3.$

Answer (score 1):

Since your question states "Prove", here is an $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-proof:

Firstly note that $$\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1$$

We must now prove that for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $$0<|x-1|<\delta \implies |(x^2+x+1)-3|=|x^2+x-2|<\varepsilon$$

---

**Firstly some rough work:**

\begin{align}\bigg|x^2 + x -2\bigg| &= \bigg|\bigg((x-1)+1\bigg)^2 + \bigg((x-1)+1\bigg)-2\bigg| \\ &=\bigg|(x-1)^2 +3(x-1)\bigg| \\ &\le\big|(x-1)^2\big| + \big|3(x-1)\big| \\ &= \big|x-1\big|^2 +3\big|x-1\big| \\ &<\big|x-1\big| +3\big|x-1\big|~~~~~~~~~~ \text{assuming $|x-1|<1$} \\ &=4\big|x-1\big|\end{align}

---

**Now for our formal proof:**

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given.

Choose $\delta= \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{4}\}$ then $$0<|x-1|<\delta\implies|x^2+x-2|<4|x-1|<4\bigg(\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\bigg)=\varepsilon$$ and we are done.

---